# What is incorrect in this List<List>?

Tags: c#, .net, list, declaration

This seems correct :

```
IList<IList<string>> MyList = new List<IList<string>>();
IList<string> List_Temp = new List<string>();
MyList .Add(List_Temp );
```

This seems incorrect :

```
IList<List<string>> MyList = new List<List<string>>();
IList<string> List_Temp = new List<string>();
MyList .Add(List_Temp );
```

why the second is incorrect?

Comment: object type should be same every time when you are adding into list your mylist list object type is list and you used to add iList in it

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because you're trying to add some `IList` implementation istead of `List` class, which is requirement by definition - IList<**List**>. Look at this:

```
IList<List<string>> MyList = new List<List<string>>();
IList<string> List_Temp = new Collection<string>(); // ooops!
MyList .Add(List_Temp );
```

The second line of sample is correct, because `Collection<T>` implements `IList<T>`, but the third line is incorrect, because `Collection<T>` doesn't inherit `List<T>`.

Comment: So that List_Temp become a Collection<string> or a List<string>?

Comment: @markzzz: A `Collection<string>`, of course. The real type of *object*, which variable `List_Temp` refers, is defined at the *right* from the assignment operator. The type of *variable* `List_Temp` is defined as `IList<string>`. Note, that these types are not equivalent each other in general. But, of course, the type of *variable* must be assignable from *object* type.

Comment: So why I don't just use `Collection<string> List_Temp = new Collection<string>();` ? Which are the advantages? Can you give to me an example? I Never understand this... (and I use to be a Java programmer)

Comment: @markzzz: e.g., `List_Temp` is a class member. I want to initialize it with `Collection<string>` in constructor, and I want to limit the rest of my code by using `IList<string>`.

Comment: "and I want to limit the rest of my code by using IList<string>" why? That's I don't understand. If I know it will become a Collection, I just decleare it as Collection :) Not through an interface :O

Comment: @markzzz: because there may be several reasons to do this, and I can't enumerate them all. E.g., I've written a T4 template, which outputs a partial class and I want it to be extended by someone. My (templated) part of this class contains logic, which needs some field to be `MySpecialCollection<T>`, but this is an implementation detail, which can be changed. So, I've declared class member with 'IList<T>', and when I will change T4 template, existing code will not be broken. Another example: reusing one variable in the same scope.

Answer (score 3):

`MyList` contains elements of type `List<string>` but you are trying to add an element of type `IList<string>`.

Answer (score 1):

Compiler says that it cannot cast `"System.Collections.Generic.IList<string>"` to `"System.Collections.Generic.List<string>"`;

`List<T>` is defined as follows:

```
public class List<T> : IList<T>, ICollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>, IList, ICollection, IEnumerable
```

while `IList<T>` is

```
public interface IList<T> : ICollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable
```

So, `List<T>` can be cast to `IList<T>`. Not vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

object type should be same every time when you are adding into list your mylist list object type is list and you used to add iList in it